# Why isn't onDestroy event of a service launched in Android Studio project?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-service

When I start `ActivityMain` in Code 1, a service will be launched, and the service will be destroied after the  `ActivityMain` is destroied , you can see Image 1 for result, it's just like my expected.

In Code 2, I hope to delay to destroy the service, but I find the `onDestroy` event of a service isn't launched in Code 2,  you can see Image 2, why ?

BTW,  After I l re-lauch Code 2,  I find there is new hash value for the service, it seems that the service is destroied and re-created.

**Code 1**

```
class ActivityMain : ComponentActivity() {
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        serviceTranslateIntent = Intent(this, ServiceTranslate::class.java)
        this.startService(serviceTranslateIntent)

        log(System.currentTimeMillis().toString()+" Hash: "+ this.hashCode()+" Create Activity" )
    }
  
    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        log(System.currentTimeMillis().toString()+" Hash: "+ this.hashCode()+" Destroy Activity" )
        this.stopService(serviceTranslateIntent)
    }
}

class ServiceTranslate: Service() {   
 
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        log(System.currentTimeMillis().toString()+" Hash: "+ this.hashCode()+" Create Server" )
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        log(System.currentTimeMillis().toString()+" Hash: "+ this.hashCode()+" Destroy Server" )
    }
}
```

**Code 2**

```
class ActivityMain : ComponentActivity() {
    // The same
  
    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        log(System.currentTimeMillis().toString()+" Hash: "+ this.hashCode()+" Destroy Activity" )
         
        val aa = this
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            log(System.currentTimeMillis().toString()+" Hash: "+ this.hashCode()+" Destroy Scope" )
            delay(5000)
            aa.stopService(serviceTranslateIntent)
        }

       // I will get the same result with the code below
       // val aa = this
       // Handler().postDelayed({
       //     log(System.currentTimeMillis().toString()+" Hash: "+ this.hashCode()+" Destroy Scope" )
       //      aa.stopService(serviceTranslateIntent)
       // }, 2000)

    }
}

//The same
```

**Image 1**

[image]

**Image 2**

[image]

Comment: Inside your coroutine or Handler's runnable, you should use `this@ActivityMain.hashCode()` instead of `this.hashCode()`. Your current code is logging the hash of the lambda function or lambda receiver (CoroutineScope) which could be misleading

Answer (score 0):

i think you should not handle asynchronous in onDestroy. If you want to turn off the timer to turn off the service, you can handle it right in the service

Answer (score 0):

`lifecycleScope` is bound to the scope of the Activity lifecycle, so when the Activity reaches the *destroyed* state, all of the CoroutineScope's coroutines are cancelled, and new ones (like yours) won't even start. [Here is the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/LifecycleOwner#(androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner).lifecycleScope()) about it being cancelled when the destroyed state is reached.

As for why it seems to have given you a new service instance on relaunch, it is possible your app completely relaunched since it was last on screen. There is not enough info provided to be sure what happened there, but I see the new activity was created 11 seconds since it was previously destroyed.

If you are simply backing out of the main activity so your app goes off screen, then it is probably killing your service instantly. Background services are not guaranteed to be kept alive while your app is off-screen. It might not even be calling your service's `onDestroy()` if it's just killing your app, although I wouldn't expect this behavior to be likely on a modern device with such a low-memory app.

Comment: Thanks! How to shut down a service at least 5 minutes after turning off the screen ?

Comment: You must use a [foreground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services) if you want it to stay alive while your app is off screen. You can make it shut itself off in its own logic.

Comment: Thanks, I only require a service keeping run at least 5 minutes after I turning off the screen.  I know  foreground service  will kepp running and a notification icon will be displayed when  turning off the screen.

Comment: Yes, but a foreground service is absolutely the only way to ensure a service lasts more than a few seconds after your app goes off screen.

Answer (score 0):

In `onDestroy` first you called super method that will destroy your visible components of activity and coroutines as well but after destroying you are creating one more coroutines that will access activity object to stop service. Now as destroy method will launch coroutines and finish it's work.

After 5 seconds you are accessing aa which is activity object.
Now there is two option one is crash for accessing activity outside and other is to create new lifecycle to stop setvice.
In second case it will create new lifecycle and on create it will call new service to create and execute and lifecycle will not be destroy because no view is destroying

If you want to destroy service after some seconds then you should create core thread that is seperate from lifecycle and will run in background forever.